# How To Remove Title Bar on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

[**Hello. I am new to this. How can i remove the title bar on top of my application? **][1]

[1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANrvg.jpg

*This is my activity main*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*this is the manifest*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bendoy.bft"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:roundicon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name="com.bendoy.bft.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: doesn't have anything to do with your android manifest, the manifest basically just describes permissions your app uses and where your app can go, it's probably in your styles.xml

Answer (score 0):

add theme to your activity reference in manifest with no title bar

just like

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```